# how to do "if firstOrNew then increment"?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently building a website with a table that counts how many times the users used the coupon.

This is the line that I used to increment. It worked well but it increments every time the page was refreshed.

```
\App\Coupon::where('coupon_id','=',$coupon[0]->coupon_id)->increment('no_paid');
```

I wanted this to increment only once even though the page was refreshed multiple times. Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a session for that. Here's an example (using Laravels global session helper):

```
if (!session()->has('coupon_used')) {
    \App\Coupon::where('coupon_id','=',$coupon[0]->coupon_id)->increment('no_paid');
    session()->put('coupon_used', true);
}
```

This first checks if the session exists. If it doesn't, it runs the code and sets the session. The second time the page is loaded, the session will be set and the code won't run.

#### Alternatively

The above code only allows for one coupon per user session, regardless if they try different coupon ID's. If you want to add the same functionality, while allowing different coupons (being able to increment once/coupon id), then you can do this:

```
if (!session()->has('coupon_' . $coupon[0]->coupon_id)) {
    \App\Coupon::where('coupon_id','=',$coupon[0]->coupon_id)->increment('no_paid');
    session()->put('coupon_' . $coupon[0]->coupon_id, true);
}
```

This does the same thing, but sets a session for just that coupon ID (since it dynamically creates the session name to have the ID appended).

Comment: Thank you very much :) wait what is 'coupon_used'?

Comment: It's just a name.. you can change it to what ever you want. It could be: `session()->has('donald_duck')` and then `session()->put('donald_duck', true)`, if you prefer.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. I like how you think. I really need the alternative code because a user can use more than 1 coupon

Comment: @JaneDoe - No probs. Feel free to upvote, as well. ;-)

Comment: I can't. I don't have enough reputation :D